# Azure KeyVault : Getting System.TypeLoadException while trying to create keyvaultclient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.'
```

The following code runs perfectly in a console app on its own but when I'm try to wrap it in a class library and call it from a webjob it throws the above error

```
public static KeyVaultClient KeyVaultClientProvider()
    {
        if(AssertionCert!=null){GetCert();}

        return new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
    }
```

I'm using .Net framework 4.7.1 and latest version of ADAL and AKV nugets.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the version of System.Net.Http? Also please share stack trace?

Comment: System.Net.Http version 4.0.0.0 runtime version (v4.0.30319)

Comment: Update to 4.3 would solve the issue. I once encountered and had to update the version. Verify if the update is allowed and doesn't break your compability.